# VSTS SDK store and retrieve value that persists between phases

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

I want to write a task in VSTS that persists a value between phases. The purpose is so I could store a value that points to a record in an external system, and then retrieve and update that record in a later phase that always executes during a release failure. I tried writing an environment variable, but that does not persist:

```
write-output("##vso[task.setvariable variable=CRQID;]$changeid")
```

I see you can write an attachment (below), but I can't find any reference to a "get-attachment" cmdlet in the SDK:

```
write-output "##vso[task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=Change Request;]$fileName"
```

I was referencing this [document](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md).

I thought I might be able to write the file to the file system, but then if the agents were pooled and my second phase executed on another agent the path would be worthless.

Answer (score 1):

For VSTS itself, it can not persist values between phases. But you can archieve it by developing your own task.

And as you found, if you stored the value in the build agent of first phase, the value can not be found if you use another agent in the second phase.

Actually you just need to **store the value to a place where both phases (different agents) can get the value**. Such as you can store the value in your github repo by below commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/reponame
#copy filename under reponame folder (overwrite of the filename already exist under reponame folder)
cd repo name 
git add .
git commit -m 'store values in the filename'
git push https://username:password@github.com/ master
```

If you want to use the value in another phase, then clone the github repo and get the value from the `filename`.